# Add more than one host to user login privileges in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

[image]

As the title reads, I want to add more than one host into the *Host* field in phpMyAdmin's user privileges, to allow a user to login from a number of different hostnames.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just add the same user multiple times under different hosts, like so:

[image: Sample PMA users table]

You can also just create one wildcard host user.

[image: Another image of creating the user.]

Comment: Thanks, this is what I am currently doing, but I would like to have just the _one_ user entry. :)

Answer (score 2):

Under "Host", try a %. like 192.168.0.% will do the whole network.

Comment: What if I want to add a range of hosts? like 192.168.0.100 - 192.168.0.200?

Comment: @MaxKielland you can also use _ as a wildcard like 192.168.0.1__ to match 100 -199 but for 200 you need to create a seperate account or use the % wildcard and include 0-99 and 201-255 too.